# Modbus rtu slave is not responding to modbus rtu master

Tags: c, embedded, serial-communication, modbus, telecommunication

https://code.google.com/p/stm32modbus/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F%20stm32modbus%20--username%20ickingdom%40gmail.com%253Fstate%253Dclosed

I am using this program.I debug and compile it successfully no error i got then i burn it into my prototype slave which has stm32f103c6 microcontroller. Then with help of docklight software i send request to my salve but its not responding. What should i do?
I set baud rate of master and slave same so that is not the issue.
I was thinking like may be program has some error but i didn't get it. So please help me to find any missing thing in this program which i have downloaded from google code which link i have shown above.Is there any alternative that you want to suggest then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the CRC request on input data and then try communicating via docklight, please be sure that the CRC module of the code is working properly.